# Intellij IDEA's code completion in build.gradle.kts doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I've installed IDEA 2020.1 Ultimate & Gradle 6.1. And I have non-working code completion in build.gradle.kts file. New empty project, old project - no matters, code completion doesn't work. IDEA doesn't see any gradle packages. Auto-completion only suggests code from kotlin base package. The last time when I had to modify a build file - it definitely worked the right way.

Does anybody know possible reasons \ fixes ?

Ubuntu 19.10, Intellij IDEA 2020.1, Grade 6.1 + Kotlin 1.3.72

Comment: Make sure you have imported the file as a Gradle project (from the file's context menu -> `Import Gradle Project` action).

Comment: @Andrey I'm sure It's imported as a Gradle project because I see project's name along with gradle build file's one